# Can we use equivalent of SF Symbol on Android device in flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, icons, sf-symbols

I'm creating a Flutter project and I really like to use SF Symbol (official iOS icons). I have found packages like `flutter_icons` that allows us to use equivalent. I would like to know if I can use them on an Android device, without any problems of copyrights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they will work fine. Actually there are a bunch of packages that you can use for that purpose like [flutter_sfsymbols](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sfsymbols). And no matter what platform are you testing your app on, it will have the same icon once you use in the code. And as a reminder for using this package in your project try following steps:

1. Open `pubspec.yaml`, and add the `flutter_sfsymbols` dependency and also the needed fonts (They are already in the package you just need to add them to your pubspec file) (your pubspec should be something like this) :

   ```
    name: example
    description: A new Flutter application.
    version: 1.0.0+1

    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter

    cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
    flutter_sfsymbols: ^1.0.0

    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter

    flutter:

    uses-material-design: true

    fonts:

    - family: sficonsets
      fonts:
        - asset: packages/flutter_sfsymbols/fonts/sficonsets.ttf
   ```
2. Run flutter pub get in the terminal, or click Packages get in IntelliJ or Android Studio.
3. Import the library in your dart file (or try the code below as your main.dart):

   ```
    import 'package:flutter_sfsymbols/flutter_sfsymbols.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: DemoPage(),
        );
      }
    }

    class DemoPage extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Icon(SFSymbols.airplane),
          ),
        ));
      }
    }
   ```
4. Run the app.

Note : All SF Symbols shall be considered to be system-provided images as defined in the Xcode and Apple SDKs license agreements and are subject to the terms and conditions set forth therein. You may not use SF Symbols—or glyphs that are substantially or confusingly similar—in your app icons, logos, or any other trademark-related use. Apple reserves the right to review and, in its sole discretion, require modification or discontinuance of use of any Symbol used in violation of the foregoing restrictions, and you agree to promptly comply with any such request.

Answer (score 3):

These assets may work on Android. However, I interpret the licensing terms to mean that you can only legally use them for software running on Apple devices. I'm no lawyer. However, this paragraph from near the top of the license agreement seems pretty clear to me.

> IMPORTANT NOTE: THE APPLE SOFTWARE IS TO BE USED SOLELY FOR CREATING
> USER INTERFACES TO BE USED IN SOFTWARE PRODUCTS RUNNING ON APPLE’S
> iOS, iPadOS, macOS, tvOS OR watchOS OPERATING SYSTEMS, AS APPLICABLE,
> AND IS SUBJECT TO THE SPECIFIC USE RESTRICTIONS SET FORTH HEREIN.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33522005)

Comment: Hmmm…it seems to me to directly answer the OP’s question about risk of copyright infringement.